# Trouble reaching a local database through ConnectionString

Tags: web-config, connection-string, configurationmanager

I have a `connectionstring`in my `web.config`, and I'm trying to call it from a `class`file.

Why does it have problems reaching the database. The database is on the local computer, inside the project.

The Class

```
public static SqlConnection createConnection()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Database"]);
    con.Open();
    return con;
}
```

and the web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="server=.\SQLEXPRESS;uid=The_Kettle_LibraryU;pwd=-5$G)dO:}B7X;Database=The_Kettle_Library" name="Database" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The error posted.

```
Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.SqlConnection(string)' has some invalid arguments

Source Error:
Line 11:     public static SqlConnection createConnection()
Line 12:     {
Line 13:         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"]);
Line 14:         con.Open();
Line 15:         return con;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be using:

`ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString`

Comment: what error message are you getting? add that to your question please :)

Comment: eek - i forgot to add the `.ConnectionString` property - i've updated my answer - try that!